# In a diagram, the arrow that does not reach the middle of the child's upper side

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

Using `tikzpicture`, I want the length of the arrows to be self-adjusting so that the arrows always arrive in the middle of each child's upper side. Currently I have fixed length in the following MWE. Specifically in this example, I would like the length of the arrows going to "child1" and "child3" to be adjusted automatically to come to the middle of the child's top side. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}


\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzset{startstop/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30}}
\tikzset{io/.style = {trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30}}
\tikzset{process/.style = {rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30}}
\tikzset{decision/.style = {diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30}}
\tikzset{arrow/.style = {thick,->,>=stealth}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title[tikzpicture with beamer]{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{tikzpicture}{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]

\node (root) [process] {root};
\node (child1) [process, below of=root, xshift=-4cm] {child1};
\draw [arrow] (root) -- (child1);

\node<+(1)-> (child2) [process, below of=root, xshift=0cm] {child2};
\draw<.(1)-> [arrow] (root) -- (child2);


\tikzset{process/.style = {rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=blue!30}}
\node<+(1)-> (child3) [process, below of=root, xshift=4cm] {child3};
\draw<.(1)-> [arrow] (root) -- (child3);


\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the arrows to enter nodes, simply specify `(child1.north)` and so on.

Like this?

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}


\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzset{startstop/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30}}
\tikzset{io/.style = {trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30}}
\tikzset{process/.style = {rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30}}
\tikzset{decision/.style = {diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30}}
\tikzset{arrow/.style = {thick,->,>=stealth}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title[tikzpicture with beamer]{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{tikzpicture}{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]

\node (root) [process] {root};
\node (child1) [process, below of=root, xshift=-4cm] {child1};
\draw [arrow] (root) -- (child1.north);

\node<+(1)-> (child2) [process, below of=root, xshift=0cm] {child2};
\draw<.(1)-> [arrow] (root) -- (child2.north);


\tikzset{process/.style = {rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=blue!30}}
\node<+(1)-> (child3) [process, below of=root, xshift=4cm] {child3};
\draw<.(1)-> [arrow] (root) -- (child3.north);


\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the arrows go inside the nodes, which is not something that I wanted. Could they be adjusted to stay on top of the nodes but horizontally on the center of the nodes?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood what you were saying here: **I want that the length of the arrows be auto-adjusted so that the incoming arrows to a block always enter at the center of the node.** ? What exactly do you want, whether it enter in the node or not?

Comment: @Curious As I understand it, you want the arrow to arrive in the **middle of the top side** of each node  *(and not in the center of the node)*. I've updated my answer to do that.

Comment: Exactly, feel free to edit the question to be more precise and helpful for others. Also, could you possibly point to the page where all these options (e.g. north, center) are enumerated.